# Streaming HLS Video from S3 with Golang

Tags: go, amazon-s3, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to create video streaming server that serve HLS video (m3u8) that is stored in S3 using Go.

Here is my code:

```
e.GET("/video", func(c echo.Context) error {
    // download file m3u8
    buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
    _, err := s3downloader.DownloadWithContext(ctx, buf, &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey), // hls/master.m3u8
    })

    return c.Stream(http.StatusOK, "application/x-mpegURL", bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
})
```

When I execute `localhost:1234/video` from Insomnia/postman, it correctly returns m3u8 file, which is the same as I execute S3 URL directly (https://xxx.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xxx/hls/master.m3u8)

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800800,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401e,mp4a.40.2"
360pixel/list.m3u8

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=965800,RESOLUTION=854x480,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2"
480pixel/list.m3u8

#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1267200,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2"
720pixel/list.m3u8
```

But, when I execute from browser, the video that served by my golang server can't be played as the s3 server does.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: There are many things that could be wrong, but the first that should cause any specification-compliant client to fail to play is the presence of multiple `EXT-X-VERSION` tags - this is forbidden and a client must fail if it encounters this. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-hls-rfc8216bis#section-4.4.1.2.

Comment: Why not let S3 serve this directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the video that served by my golang server can't be played as the s3 server does.

There could be two issues in your code:

1. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not set to `*`.

   ```golang
   e.GET("/video", func(c echo.Context) error {
       // download file m3u8
       buf := aws.NewWriteAtBuffer([]byte{})
       _, err := s3downloader.DownloadWithContext(ctx, buf, &s3.GetObjectInput{
           Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
           Key:    aws.String(objectKey), // hls/master.m3u8
       })

       c.Response().Header().Set(echo.HeaderAccessControlAllowOrigin, "*")
       return c.Stream(http.StatusOK, "application/x-mpegURL", bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
   })
   ```
2. The following paths are relative to the original request. If the master `m3u8` file is served by your golang server, the request to the embedded `m3u8` file goes to your golang server. So you should either change your golang server to serve the embedded `m3u8` files or convert them to absolute URLs (that points to the object stored in S3).

   ```
   ...
   360pixel/list.m3u8
   ...
   480pixel/list.m3u8
   ...
   720pixel/list.m3u8
   ```